# Fetch api error

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs, fetch

Hola en mi pagina web he hecho un formulario en el cual ocupo `fetch`

```
state = { error: false };
  input = ({ target: { value, name } }) => this.setState({ [name]: value });
  submitData = async () => {
    if (!this.handleValidation())return
    let body = this.state;
    body = JSON.stringify({ ...this.state, platform: "SPOT" });
    console.log(body)
    const data = await fetch("linkDeAmazon/working", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
      },
      body
    });
    const json = await data.text();
    console.log(json);
    this.setState({done:true})
  };
```

Al darle al darle enviar al formulario no lo envía y en la consola me aparece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trabajo con `reactjs`, me dijeron que ocupara `mode: 'no cors'`, pero no entiendo como hacerlo soy aun novato en esto

Comment: busca CORS, hay varias preguntas en el sitio muy parecidas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

agregando el `mode: 'no-cors'` se soluciono el problema

```
state = { error: false };
  input = ({ target: { value, name } }) => this.setState({ [name]: value });
  submitData = async () => {
    if (!this.handleValidation())return
    let body = this.state;
    body = JSON.stringify({ ...this.state, platform: "Contact us SPOT" });
    console.log(body)
    const data = await fetch("link de amazon/working", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
      },
      body,
      mode: 'no-cors'
    });
    const json = await data.text();
    console.log(json);
    this.setState({done:true})
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu servidor Node.js
Agrega 
instala el paquete Cors con npm install cors
despues agregalo con 
const cors = require('cors')

Comment: Hola Eduardo, me parece que esta respuesta no puede ser lo que el OP está necesitando, ni siquiera ha dicho si el backend está escrito o no en NodeJS, por lo que la solución que propones puede variar si está usando otro lenguaje de programación en el backend. Si quieres hacer anotaciones puedes usar los comentarios

Comment: la parte de back me acab de informar que el servidor es NGINX